# Computing aggregate by creating nested dictionary on the fly

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by, aggregate

I'm new to python and I could really use your help and guidance at the moment. I am trying to read a csv file with three cols and do some computation based on the first and second column i.e.

```
A   spent   100     A   spent   2040
A   earned  60
B   earned  48
B   earned  180
A   spent   40
.
.
.
```

Where A spent 2040 would be the addition of all 'A' and 'spent' amounts. This does not give me an error but it's not logically correct:

```
for row in rows:
    cols = row.split(",")
    truck = cols[0]
    if (truck != 'A' and truck != 'B'):
        continue
    record = cols[1]
    if(record != "earned" and record != "spent"):
        continue
    amount = int(cols[2])
    #print(truck+" "+record+" "+str(amount))

    if truck in entries:
        #entriesA[truck].update(record)
        if record in records:
            records[record].append(amount)
        else:
            records[record] = [amount]
    else:
        entries[truck] = records
        if record in records:
            records[record].append(amount)
        else:
            entries[truck][record] = [amount]
print(entries)
```

I am aware that this part is incorrect because I would be adding the same inner dictionary list to the outer dictionary but I'm not sure how to go from there:

```
entries[truck] = records
if record in records:
    records[record].append(amount)
```

However, Im not sure of the syntax to create a new dictionary on the fly that would not be 'records'

I am getting:

```
{'B': {'earned': [60, 48], 'spent': [100]}, 'A': {'earned': [60, 48], 'spent': [100]}}
```

But hoping to get:

```
{'B': {'earned': [48]}, 'A': {'earned': [60], 'spent': [100]}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The term for this is *"A's aggregate spending was 2040"*. And yes pandas package does this and is highly recommended.

Comment: Better to phrase the question *"How to compute aggregate?"* than asking about implementation *"creating nested dictionary"*. Read about the split-apply-combine paradigm.

Comment: In your expected result, why do you expect the earned for B to be 48 rather than 228? Similarly for A spent, shouldn't it be 140? You mentioned the sum in your question, but now it seems you just want the first one?

Answer (score 2):

For the kind of calculation you are doing here, I highly recommend [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Assuming `in.csv` looks like this:

```
truck,type,amount
A,spent,100
A,earned,60
B,earned,48
B,earned,180
A,spent,40
```

You can do the totalling with three lines of code:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('in.csv')
totals = df.groupby(['truck', 'type']).sum()
```

`totals` now looks like this:

```
              amount
truck type          
A     earned      60
      spent      140
B     earned     228
```

You will find that Pandas allows you to think on a much higher level and avoid fiddling with lower level data structures in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if record in entries[truck]:
    entries[truck][record].append(amount)
else:
    entries[truck][record] = [amount]
```

I believe this is what you would want? Now we are directly accessing the truck's records, instead of trying to check a local dictionary called `records`. Just like you did if there wasn't any entry of a truck.

Comment: Thanks @Nysten but I still have the same problem